# which version of SQLserver do I have?

Tags: sql-server

the SQL server that I am accessing via SQL Server management Studio, show me a number 10.50, but I need the actual commercial name, for example if is an SQL Server 2012, 2008 R2 or whatever.

How can I retrieve this information?

Thx

Comment: select @@VERSION

Answer (score 2):

```
PRINT @@VERSION;
```

Simple as that. A quick Google would have given you this answer.

Comment: thx for your quick answer!